# Interaction between Electron and Angular JS

Tags: electron, ipc, interaction

I have developed a desktop application using electron by wrapping my webpage with electron.
Now how to make my webpage and electron interact i.e. catching any click event inside the webpage and calling a electron function in main.js etc. and passing some data from electron to webpage.

Note: my webpage is developed using angular 1.5

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check the electron quick start repository before going on.

https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start

https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos

In order to communicate between the main and renderer process you should take a look at the ipcMain and ipcRenderer ([ipcMain](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md)).

Just for reference here is the sample provided in the documentation.

```
// In main process.
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "ping"
  event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', 'pong')
})

ipcMain.on('synchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "ping"
  event.returnValue = 'pong'
})


// In renderer process (web page).
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping')) // 
prints "pong"

ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "pong"
})
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping')
```

Comment: this will work fine when your webpage is built on Angular 2 or more but i am asking for a scenario with angular 1.x/1.5

Comment: Since I'm using this in an AngularJS 1.6 application I can not agree with your statement. Can you please give more details why this should not work?

Comment: @DEDaniel : Where do we define  "const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')" . Is it in controller or somewhere else.